# Discovering wifi-direct device

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I am trying out one example with of wifi-Direct for android.

I have run the the demo application on two different android phones.

Is it that both the application needs active wifi AP?
Is it necessary that we need to connect both the device to same wifi AP?
Is it that disabling wifi on the device will disconnect the wifi-direct session?

Can some one point me to one simple (basic) example of wifi-direct.

Comment: You do not want two devices to connect to a wireless access point to setup a WiFi direct connection.if you disable WiFi ,  WiFi-direct session will also get disconnected. What you  meant by a wifi AP?A wireless access point ?

Answer (score 2):

Android setting app can search and connect via wifi direct

4.0

setting app -> wireless setting other -> wi-fi direct (checked)
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/android-4.0.1_r1.1/src/com/android/settings/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pSettings.java

if this activity didn't shows on your device, try create shortcut app, such as

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut

currently disabled p2psettings activity on AOSP source code.

so i'm strongly recommended 4.1 later device.

4.1 later

setting app -> wireless setting -> (menu) -> wi-fi direct

my test app shows how to use wifi direct api.

https://github.com/kensuke/WiFiDirectTestApp

Comment: @Varun, and Kensuke Sato,..... could you guys check out my similar case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24357892/how-to-solve-discovering-other-device-via-wi-fi-android-api?noredirect=1#comment37663295_24357892

Answer (score 1):

According to [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html):

> Wi-Fi peer-to-peer (P2P) allows Android 4.0 (API level 14) or later
>   devices with the appropriate hardware to connect directly to each
>   other via Wi-Fi without an intermediate access point (Android's Wi-Fi
>   P2P framework complies with the Wi-Fi Alliance's Wi-Fi Direct™
>   certification program).

So, you don't need to connect to any access point. just enable wifi and start to search available devices to connect.

disable wifi will disconnect wifi direct connection.

here is my app shows wifi direct connection and transfer files.

https://github.com/Youxian-Chen/WiFiDirectTransfer

hope this helps.